# Convert abc notation to wav file

Tags: python, deep-learning

Recently I am working on the music generation project using deep learning. I am not able to convert my model generated abc notation to wav file. Is there is any way to do this? I want to upload it into soundcloud in .wav format. I research a lot but I could not find it.

Comment: What library are you using? any information other than just the issue helps us answer your question

Comment: I suggest you ask on the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

There are existing tools to convert an ABC file to a WAV file, but remember that the formats represent fundamentally different information:  ABC is a shorthand musical notation and WAV is an audio format.  You need additional performance information (like instruments) to turn notation into sound.

That said, you might try PySynth: https://mdoege.github.io/PySynth/